# I want to show multiple FBML pages to on one page

Tags: facebook, fbml

I want to add multiple FBML pages to my facebook page. i cannot able to show more than one page link at left side below profile picture. See here http://www.facebook.com/pages/My-FBML-Research/156894617695018  (MY FBML PAGE) . i want to add one more above this page with name "Welcome".

I have seen that many facebook people having this. what i need but i cannot able to do. 
See here : http://www.facebook.com/pages/ChatterBox-Media-Marketing/156068134423852?sk=app_7146470109

Comment: each "link" (tab in old style) is an application. if you use some of the FBML apps most (if not all) can only add one of this tabs, couse its only one app.  you can use different fbml apps which provide the same features.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Can you tell me which fbml app give me solution ? because i need same FBML icom like [<>] with pages.Thanks, Sandip Makwana PHP/iPhone/Android Freelancer

Comment: afaik there is no "free" app which can handle this. a tab is always a applicaiton, so the applicaiton has the icon setting. an application can only be added once to an app. i know of evolver and tabsite which registered multiple apps with the same icon and canvas code to let people have multiple of such tabs.
but the easiest way will be if you register the apps yourself and display a html site of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

FBML fan page tabs have been deprecated by Facebook.  Your best bet will be creating multiple iframe applications (one for each tab) and then setting each iframe content url to a page on your server.